How to create multiple AWS security group rules by reading multiple yaml files using terraform?
I want to create multiple aws security group rules by reading multiple yaml files located under a different directory using terraform but I am not sure how exactly can I achieve it.
Below is the folder structure:
-> env
    |
    -> prod
        |
        -> external
            |
            -> IXCC
                |
                -> values.yaml
            |
            -> IXCB
                |
                -> values.yaml

my aws_security_group_rules.tf file look like below:
module "security_group_rules" {
    source                  = "../kem-infra-modules/iam-security-group-rules"
    for_each                = fileset("${path.module}/env/prod/external/*/", "values.yaml")

    # Assuming you have output variables from your security_group module
    security_group_id       = module.security_group.security_group_id

    # Use the contents of the YAML file to populate the security group rules
    from_port               = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/env/prod/external/${dirname(each.value)}/values.yaml"))["fromPort"]
    description             = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/env/prod/external/${dirname(each.value)}/values.yaml"))["definition"]
    protocol                = upper(yamldecode(file("${path.module}/env/prod/external/${dirname(each.value)}/values.yaml"))["protocol"])
    to_port                 = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/env/prod/external/${dirname(each.value)}/values.yaml"))["toPort"]
    type                    = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/env/prod/external/${dirname(each.value)}/values.yaml"))["type"]
    cidr_blocks             = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/env/prod/external/${dirname(each.value)}/values.yaml"))["sourceIpCidrs"]

}

My values.yaml files under each folder looks like below:
IXCB - values.yaml:

fromPort: 443
definition: testing
protocol: tcp
toPort: 443
type: ingress
sourceIpCidrs: ["xx.xx.xx.xx/32", "xx.xx.xx.xx/32", "xx.xx.xx.xx/32"]

IXCC - values.yaml:

fromPort: 443
definition: testing
protocol: tcp
toPort: 443
type: ingress
sourceIpCidrs: ["xx.xx.xx.xx/32", "xx.xx.xx.xx/32", "xx.xx.xx.xx/32"]

I am expecting two security group rules to be created but the plan stage shows 0 to add,0 to change & 0 to delete.
I also tried using locals but that too didnt work:
locals.tf:
locals {
  security_group_rules = flatten([
    for dir in fileset("${path.module}/env/prod/external", "*") : [
      for mapping in yamldecode(file("${path.module}/env/prod/external/${dir}/values.yaml"))["principalMappings"] : {
        customer_name = dir
        from_port     = mapping.fromPort
        description   = mapping.definition
        protocol      = upper(mapping.protocol)
        to_port       = mapping.toPort
        type          = mapping.type
        cidr_blocks   = mapping.sourceIpCidrs
      }
    ]
  ])
}

tried calling this locals into the aws security group rules. it still failed.

Did anything else exist prior to adding security groups? Also, can you try something like yamldecode(file(each.key))["fromPort"]?

I expect this isn't the whole solution, but note that the pattern (i.e. wildcard) for fileset goes in the second argument, not the first argument. e.g. something like fileset("${path.module}/env/prod/external", "*/values.yaml")

The first argument is the directory to begin searching from, so it must be an exact path rather than a wildcard pattern.

But I want it iterate inside the external dir. Read the values.yml from each of them

Since I don't have the code from the module you are using, I will give an example of how to create security group rules locally:
locals {
  sg_rules_path = "${path.module}/env/prod/external"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "test" {

}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "test" {
  for_each          = fileset(local.sg_rules_path, "*/values.yaml")
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.test.id
  description       = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).definition
  from_port         = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).fromPort
  protocol          = upper(yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).protocol)
  to_port           = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).toPort
  type              = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).type
  cidr_blocks       = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).sourceIpCidrs
}

I have named your example YML files sg1 and sg2 and stored them at the same level as the root module. This will yield the following output:
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_security_group.test will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group" "test" {
      + arn                    = (known after apply)
      + description            = "Managed by Terraform"
      + egress                 = (known after apply)
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + ingress                = (known after apply)
      + name                   = (known after apply)
      + name_prefix            = (known after apply)
      + owner_id               = (known after apply)
      + revoke_rules_on_delete = false
      + tags_all               = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id                 = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_security_group_rule.test["sg1/values.yaml"] will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group_rule" "test" {
      + cidr_blocks              = [
          + "1.1.1.1/32",
          + "2.2.2.2/32",
          + "3.3.3.3/32",
        ]
      + description              = "testing"
      + from_port                = 443
      + id                       = (known after apply)
      + protocol                 = "tcp"
      + security_group_id        = (known after apply)
      + security_group_rule_id   = (known after apply)
      + self                     = false
      + source_security_group_id = (known after apply)
      + to_port                  = 443
      + type                     = "ingress"
    }

  # aws_security_group_rule.test["sg2/values.yaml"] will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group_rule" "test" {
      + cidr_blocks              = [
          + "4.4.4.4/32",
          + "5.5.5.5/32",
          + "6.6.6.6/32",
        ]
      + description              = "testing"
      + from_port                = 443
      + id                       = (known after apply)
      + protocol                 = "tcp"
      + security_group_id        = (known after apply)
      + security_group_rule_id   = (known after apply)
      + self                     = false
      + source_security_group_id = (known after apply)
      + to_port                  = 443
      + type                     = "ingress"
    }

Having this in mind, I would argue something like the following should work:
locals {
  sg_rules_path = "${path.module}/env/prod/external"
}

module "security_group_rules" {
    source                  = "../kem-infra-modules/iam-security-group-rules"
    for_each                = fileset(local.sg_rules_path, "*/values.yaml")

    # Assuming you have output variables from your security_group module
    security_group_id       = module.security_group.security_group_id

    # Use the contents of the YAML file to populate the security group rules
    from_port               = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).fromPort
    description             = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).definition
    protocol                = upper(yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).protocol)
    to_port                 = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).toPort
    type                    = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).type
    cidr_blocks             = yamldecode(file("${local.sg_rules_path}/${each.key}")).sourceIpCidrs
}


Hi, Thanks for the response. I cannot have the files at the root level of the module. The aws resource resides under different directory and the yml files under different directory as i have given the structure. Also, by trying yamldecode(file(each.key))["fromPort"] gave the same response as before - it isnt reading the values from those yamls. I want it to read multiple directories(IXCC & IXCB) inside the "external" dir and values.yml file within each (IXCB & IXCC)

@Shafeeq I have updated the answer and used the same path you have in your case.

your solution fits if the yaml files are within the same directory whereas I want to check for the subdirectories under external directory and each subdirectory contains the yaml file and need to read from them and create the security group rules.

Uhm, this is literally the same path as in your question: "${path.module}/env/prod/external", right? The second part of the answer checks for any YML files under "${path.module}/env/prod/external/*/values.yaml".
